# Phonegap/HTML - How to show a pdf returned by a webservice?

Tags: html, web-services, pdf

I've got a SOAP webservice that returns a binary stream of a .PDF file.

The file doesn't exists physically, I need to know if there is a way to make the browser interpret this stream like an HTML link to show generate and show the file: `<a href="url.pdf">DOWNLOAD FILE</a>`

Answer (score 0):

You can put a page in a web server that retrieves the PDF stream, sets the required parameters in the header of the response, and sends the response to the client.

Example using C# and asp.net:

The HTML link would be: `<a href="mypdf.aspx">DOWNLOAD FILE</a>`

The code in `mypdf.aspx` would be:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", 
        "attachment;filename=FilledForm.pdf");
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    byte[] bytes = GetPDFBytesFromWebService();
    Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
    Response.End();           
}
```